# MySQL INSERT WHEN field is Greater than php variable value

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a dynamic variable in php `$newtotal`.  I want to `INSERT` when this variable is Greater than my MAX Database Integer

```
$newtotal = 4000;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (`DATE`, `TOTAL`, `DBTOTAL`) VALUES ('2012-03-09', '1', '$newtotal') WHERE MAX(`DBTOTAL`) < '$newtotal'");
```

ie. And in my database my MAX(DBTOTAL) = 4050;

This should not `INSERT`; also it should `INSERT` correctly when `$newtotal` is changed  to greater than 4050 however I get syntax errors on either variable number.  Need help with the syntax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `WHERE` clauses in `INSERT` statements. You will need to check the value to see if you want to insert and do so if your conditions are met.

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT MAX(DBTOTAL)
    FROM table
");

list($max) = mysql_fetch_num($result);

if ($max < $newtotal) {
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO table (`DATE`, `TOTAL`, `DBTOTAL`) 
        VALUES ('2012-03-09', '1', '$newtotal')
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a conditional insert by basing it on a `SELECT` instead of supplying `VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`DATE`, `TOTAL`, `DBTOTAL`)
SELECT '2012-03-09', '1', '$newtotal' FROM mytable
WHERE MAX(`DBTOTAL`) < '$newtotal'
```

Comment: Then you need a `GROUP BY` on a suitable column so you only get one row as a result.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use `WHERE` with `INSERT`. An if-condition should do the trick:

```
mysql_query("
    IF '$newtotal' > (SELECT MAX(`DBTOTAL`) FROM mytable)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mytable (`DATE`, `TOTAL`, `DBTOTAL`) VALUES ('2012-03-09', '1', '$newtotal')
    END
");
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it;

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
  SELECT '2012-03-10', '1', 4051 FROM DUAL
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE m.dbtotal >= 4051
  );
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28a5e/33).